# ASP.NET MVC 3 setup for IIS7.5 with RESTful Verbs

Tags: asp.net, rest, configuration, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I have a restful controller that has your standard REST HTTP Verbs: Get,Post, Put, Delete. The problem I am having is that although my controllers are decorated to accept these verbs, when I execute my REST action, it can only hit my Get and Post methods.

I have the attributes on top of the controller actions: HttPut, HttpDelete, HttpPost, and HttpGet.

I also have the the override method in my forms: @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Put)

When I submit my form, I get a 404 error from IIS 7.5, saying the static file handler couldn't find the resource. Strangely the same forms work in Cassini, so I think it is something in IIS7.5's setup.

**What do I need to do to get IIS 7.5 to handle REST verbs like PUT and DELETE with Asp.Net MVC 3?**

I have already removed WebDAV and have looked through the handlers but the ones I am modifying seem to do nothing.

My current setup is Asp.Net MVC 3, IIS7.5 on Windows 7.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The solution is to remove the WebDAV module, but I was also using Restful-Routing library and it turned out to be a minor bug in that code that was causing strange behavior. Patched it and now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the WebDAV module, but I was also using Restful-Routing library and it turned out to be a minor bug in that code that was causing strange behavior. Patched it and now it works! –

Comment: why is WebDAV necessary to remove?

Comment: WebDAV reserves some of the verbs for itself, so when using Verbs like PUT and DELETE WebDAV can hijack your initial request. Which means your original request never reaches your application.

Comment: You have proof of this or documentation? I have WebDAV installed on my box right now and Just tested an API with `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE`.

Comment: I don't have microsoft documentation to back this up, but here is a RavenDB document showing that WebDAV might pose a problem http://ravendb.net/faq/405-method-not-allowed